# C# Console Application project to compute the total price of a transaction

Tags: arrays, .net, if-statement, c#-4.0, switch-statement

I cannot take multiple inputs from the user, calculate them, and show them on screen. There is also a scene card option for discount.If they have Scene card with them, the base price should be reduced by 10% for each item. (i.e. apples would cost $1.575 per lb and same for Tomatoes are Apples). Each Milk bag will cost $6.00 if they have scene card.

```
        Console.WriteLine("enter how many items you purchased");
        int numberOfItems = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of item purchased: ");
        string[] strings= new string[numberOfItems];    
       

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of item purchased: ");
        string itemName = Console.ReadLine();
        double weight;
        int numberOfBags;
        double basePrice = 0;
        bool hasScenaCard = false;

        switch (itemName.ToLower())
        {
            case "apples":
                basePrice = 1.75;
                break;
            case "chillies":
                basePrice = 1.29;
                break;
            case "tomatoes":
                basePrice = 1.45;
                break;
            case "milk":
                basePrice = 6.54;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid item name entered.");
                return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the weight of the item purchased (in lbs): ");
        weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of store bags used: ");
        numberOfBags = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



        Console.WriteLine("Do you have a Scena card (yes/no): ");
        hasScenaCard = Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "yes";
        if (itemName.ToLower() != "milk")
        {
            basePrice *= weight;
            if (hasScenaCard)
            {
                basePrice *= 0.10;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (hasScenaCard)
            {
                basePrice = 6.00;
            }
            basePrice *= weight;
        }
        double storeBagsCost = numberOfBags * 0.5;
        double subtotal = basePrice + storeBagsCost;
        double hstAmount = subtotal * 0.13;
        double grandTotal = subtotal + hstAmount;
        int scenePoints = (int)(weight * 20);

        Console.WriteLine("Item Name: " + itemName);
        Console.WriteLine("Base Price: $" + basePrice);
        Console.WriteLine("Store Bags Cost: $" + storeBagsCost);
        Console.WriteLine("Subtotal: $" + subtotal);
        Console.WriteLine("HST Amount: $" + hstAmount);
        Console.WriteLine("Grand Total: $" + grandTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Scene Points Earned: " + scenePoints);
```

Comment: You can use a loop. For example: `for (int itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < numberOfItems; itemNumber++) { // Read in item and do calculations... }`

Comment: See: [Use loops to repeat operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/branches-and-loops-local#use-loops-to-repeat-operations)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't changed your code too much since I assume you want that as basic as possible. Just added a `for` loop to get multiple inputs from users based on the number of purchased items.

```
 public static void GetLetters()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter how many items you purchased");
        int numberOfItems = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of item purchased: ");
        //string[] strings = new string[numberOfItems]; // I'm not sure what are these lines doing

        double weight = 0;
        int numberOfBags = 0;
        double basePrice = 0.0;
        bool hasScenaCard = false;
        string itemName = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of item purchased: ");
            itemName = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (itemName.ToLower())
            {
                case "apples":
                    basePrice = 1.75;
                    break;
                case "chillies":
                    basePrice = 1.29;
                    break;
                case "tomatoes":
                    basePrice = 1.45;
                    break;
                case "milk":
                    basePrice = 6.54;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid item name entered.");
                    return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the weight of the item purchased (in lbs): ");
            weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of store bags used: ");
            numberOfBags = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



            Console.WriteLine("Do you have a Scena card (yes/no): ");
            hasScenaCard = Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "yes";
            if (itemName.ToLower() != "milk")
            {
                basePrice *= weight;
                if (hasScenaCard)
                {
                    basePrice *= 0.10;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (hasScenaCard)
                {
                    basePrice = 6.00;
                }
                basePrice *= weight;
            }
        }

        double storeBagsCost = numberOfBags * 0.5;
        double subtotal = basePrice + storeBagsCost;
        double hstAmount = subtotal * 0.13;
        double grandTotal = subtotal + hstAmount;
        int scenePoints = (int)(weight * 20);

        Console.WriteLine("Item Name: " + itemName);
        Console.WriteLine("Base Price: $" + basePrice);
        Console.WriteLine("Store Bags Cost: $" + storeBagsCost);
        Console.WriteLine("Subtotal: $" + subtotal);
        Console.WriteLine("HST Amount: $" + hstAmount);
        Console.WriteLine("Grand Total: $" + grandTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Scene Points Earned: " + scenePoints);

    }
```

**Note** lots of validation is required to ensure you get the right type of input from users.